# How to create cron job on pyrocms?

Tags: cron, pyrocms

How can I create cron job for pyrocms? I did as I did in codeigniter but it doesn't work.

I created a cron job like: 
* * * * * php5 /var/www/test/index.php cron/crontest

here cron is the controller and crontest is function and it is working properly while running function manually

Answer (score 0):

I know... an old question, maybe someone will use in future.
Look to your controller for this code:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

So for using cron, you can remove this rule, or better is use in cron something like this:

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.yoursite.com/pathto/cron?attr=secret
```

Where is used attribute with secret code as ddos protection.